# Not able to connect to mssql db with node-mssql in Linux Machine

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, linux, node-mssql

I am trying to connect to a SQL DB SERVER with the help of mssql . I am able to connect to the DB server when the code is running on my local windows machine. But this is not working on my Linux server , its not connecting to DB.

I should be able to connect to SQL DB SERVER on Linux machine too.

I am getting the error as

src/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js: 2423
throw err

Error: error:00000000 : lib(0):func(0):reason(0)
at new Hmac(node: internal/crypto/hash:136:17)
at Object.createHmac (node: crypto:165:10)

Configuration:

```
const sqlConfig = {
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PWD,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  domain: process.env.Domain,
  server: process.env.server,
  port: process.env.port
  pool: {
    max: 10,
    min: 0,
    idleTimeoutMillis: 30000
  },
  options: {
    encrypt: true, // for azure
    trustServerCertificate: true // change to true for local dev / self-signed certs
  }
}

async () => {
 try {
  await sql.connect(sqlConfig)
  const result = await sql.query`select * from mytable where id = ${value}`
  console.log(result)
 } catch (err) {
  console.log(error)
 }
}
```

Software versions
NodeJS: 18.17.1
node-mssql: 10.0.2
SQL Server: 2019

Note: This was working with the below configuration and it started failing when updated to above mentioned configuration

Software versions
NodeJS: 16.15.0
node-mssql: 4.3.7
SQL Server: 2019

Comment: Since you're connecting to `localhost`.... does your Linux machine have Microsoft SQL Server installed as well? Which version?

Comment: Sorry I am not connecting to localhost. I have updated my question

Comment: I really hope for your sake you're using **placeholder values** and not this string interpolation recklessness.

Comment: Is your database instance on your local network, or some cloud service? Is it on a public IP? Are both your Windows and Linux machine on the same local network?

Comment: I am not using string for config, fetching the values from .env file. My application is deployed on a cloud service and it's not on public IP. Linux is my server, my laptop is windows

Comment: So when you say "Linux is my server" are you meaning that your node application is deployed to a Linux server in the cloud somewhere? Is your SQL Server also deployed somewhere in the cloud, and accessible via a public IP address? Or is it sitting on a private non-routable network somewhere such as 192.168.0.0/16 or 10.0.0.0/8?

Comment: Being a modern version of SQL Server with TLS 1.2 support it's unlikely that SQL Server 2019 would be having crypto difficulties with any modern versions of DBMS libraries. What's the output of `SELECT @@VERSION` when executed against it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to connect via local computer but not on the Linux machine it could be the URI is invalid, or the database port is not open for you to connect to it.

Comment: Nope that's not the issue as it was working before. I have added that information in my question

Comment: What do you mean it was working before, do you mean locally? I am just trying to understand your situation.

Comment: So I have this working before both on my server and local.

Comment: In version 10 in node mssql try updating the code to something like this "const sql = require('mssql')

async () => {
    try {
        // make sure that any items are correctly URL encoded in the connection string
        await sql.connect('Server=localhost,1433;Database=database;User Id=username;Password=password;Encrypt=true')
        const result = await sql.query`select * from mytable where id = ${value}`
        console.dir(result)
    } catch (err) {
        // ... error checks
    }
}". When major updates happen to a library there is often breaking changes

Comment: More ways to configure it here in the docs https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql/v/10.0.2